# Entity Framework vs Entity Framework Core interms of performance & memory consumption

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I know EF Core is a complete rewrite from ground up. Wanted to know about the performance/memory footprint improvements made in EF Core compared to EF.

Am having a .net core 3.1 web-api, I will have to use Postgresql. Wanted to know whether using an ORM(like EF Core) is a good solution?
Or is there any other better data access technology(no ORM or dapper) which can be highly performant to access Postgresql in .net core 3.1 application?

Comment: As far as I know, there is multiple test blog that is talking about the query performance or else. Like this [article](https://exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-core-query-performance-benchmarking-2019/). Normally, the best performance when you query the database is directly using sql query library, but this need a lot of codes. According to test article above,  Dapper is  faster than EF Core.

Comment: Dapper is fast in single fetch, not on the set-fetches. It really depends whether your use-case often single and/or set fetches. The official ORM benchmark can be found [here](https://github.com/FransBouma/RawDataAccessBencher/blob/4244489a0a2e3b414f5deac97a9381b8d96f0eff/Results/20200924_netcore31.txt#L47). Also, please be aware of the memory-efficiency and the simplicity of use. Please do not see this as bias comment for RepoDB. TIA

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is a valid answer as I am the author of this, but it is something that you may looking. Please have a look at [RepoDB](https://repodb.net/).